# This code for changing roles doesn't work

Tags: discord.py

I got this code to change a user's role, but it won't work.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ruleBreak(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="RuleBreakers")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

But it's causing this error

```
Ignoring exception in command ruleBreak:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/unkno/Desktop/Code_Tests/Python/discord_bot/WIP/bot2.py", line 19, in ruleBreak
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="RuleBreakers")
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'
```

What do I do, why is this happening, and where do I change it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass context as it's done for you in the rewrite branch.

```
@client.command()
async def ruleBreak(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="RuleBreakers")
    await discord.Member.add_roles(member, role)
```

EDIT: The main issue here was that `Client.add_roles` changed to `Member.add_roles()` in the rewrite version. [Migrating to v1.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#migrating-to-v1-0)